# Web service that sends html pages with code to kindle

Tags: kindle

I have a kindle and I am trying several web/cloud services that send a web page converted to kindle format to my kindle using myname@free.kindle.com.

Unfortunately I need to convert web pages that contain programming code (java, etc.) and the services I have tried fail to render the code correctly.

Are there any services that render code correctly? If so which?

Comment: I'd recommend to tell us which services you had tried already, and what was your problem with them!

Comment: I have not tracked them but the problem is the same. In most web sites the programming code is rendered via some custom css or with javascript. The above services simplify the page before sending it to kindle and so they make the programming code unreadable.

Comment: When you say code you mean formated text that is actually a code (e.g a programming book), correct? I think you have a high chance that no automatic service will correctly implement such text without much knowledge of syntax. Most code example can easy get unreadable, because the indentation creates long lines which are not break down nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [Push to Kindle](http://fivefilters.org/kindle-it/) from fivefilters? I tried a couple of webpages with java code on them and worked pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

Use [En2Kindle](http://en2kindle.com) along with Pocket or Evernote. To push web articles to Kindle, all you'll need is clip that page into Pocket or Evernote using smartphone, PC etc.

The service does format the web articles for Kindle. All unnecessary Ads, JavaScript etc. are removed. The articles will be pushed in `.mobi` format.

Answer (score 1):

[DocRaptor](https://docraptor.com/) is a web embedding of [PrinceXML](http://www.princexml.com/) and will do an excellent quality of job.